# Determining the order of poles of functions, particularly of $\frac{z^2+1}{z^4-2}$ and singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

Say I had $f(z) = \dfrac{z^2+1}{z^4-2}$.

I have found the poles, but how do I find the order of the poles?

Would they all be of order $4$ as they are $4$th roots?

Also, how would i find the singularity?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just for a bit of clarification - the order of a pole is the power, $n$, that it is raised to when written in the form $\frac{a(z)}{(z-z_0)^n}$  where $a(z_0)\neq 0$ and $a(z)$ is bounded in the vicinity of $z=z_0$.

Comment: thank you!! thought it might be.. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, they are of order one, because they are all distinct.  The poles are the singularities, so long as they do not coincide with t he zeroes of the numerator, which they do not.

Just for the record, the poles are at $z=2^{1/4} e^{i k \pi/2}$, $k \in \{0,1,2,3\}$.

Comment: great thank you very much! i thought that meant they are of order 1 but couldnt find a good enough description to confirm this is true! So if i had $ z[1-e^(1/z)]$ would the poles and singlaritity be at z=0 with order 0 this time?

Comment: @user67411: not sure, what you wrote is not clear.  But if I had to guess, $e^{1/z}$ is of infinite order as an essential singularity.